# How to set color representation for a bitmap image in wpf

Tags: wpf, colors, representation

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YwPx3.png)im working on a wpf application that should conver the jpg image to tif with a specefic attributes like 24 bitdepth 300 DPI and color representation of sRGB. i have managed to get through all of them except the color representation. The client requires the color representation as mandatory and i dont know how to make that possible. Please help
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [this](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BitMiracle.LibTiff.NET/) library you can manipulate the tags for Tiff files, one of which should be the colour you are after.

Comment: thank u for the helpful answer but i encountered a problem i dont know how to set the icc profile of the tiff image to sRGB. If you can let me know that wpuld be very hepful . Thankyou

Comment: From reading the documentation it seems the tag you want is ICCPROFILE. You can use the code from the documentation here https://bitmiracle.github.io/libtiff.net/ under the sample "How to write TIFF tags before data "

Comment: i asked for how to use iccprofile but unfortunately i didnot find what i wanted :( in that article

Comment: Here is the link to a list of the tags https://bitmiracle.github.io/libtiff.net/html/004b29cb-3828-19ac-b924-95671b477f08.htm .This has the tag ICCPROFILE just over half way down.